# git terminal commit bug

Tags: ios, xcode, git, tfs

I am using `git` on terminal ... i have been committing adding files pushing since forever now, i just lost 2 weeks of work, because 
git commits were just files without code ?? have someone ever experienced such an issue ?, i check the project repo now .. and all i see is my files with the header comment and Zero code in them ... is there a way to recover that code that i know 100% i wrote committed and pushed at some point .. 
we are using *TFS* for our repo ...

How did i know... i jumped into the Xcode source control tools, tried to commit after i committed in terminal .. and there it is all files there with all the code i wrote as insertion commit ..

Commands i used : 
`git add .` , `git commit -m ""` , `git push`

I had 3  - 4 commits before pushing once, i don't know if this is relevant

Comment: May you show us the commands used and their output? Also it'd be very useful to see the result of `git status` and `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.

Comment: i used git add . , git commit -m "" , git push

Comment: Please may you edit the question rather than adding information as a comment? Also may you provide the results of the commands used, especially the ones I mentioned.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry ..  i know how SO works i am just so pissed atm ill edit

Comment: Thanks, that's much appreciated.